# Cannot run my shiny App - Error in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm trying to run my own shiny App but I always receive an error message in the console. Here is the warning message:

```
Loading required package: shiny
Warning in base::file(file, encoding = enc) :
  'raw = FALSE' but '/Users/octaviodelsueldo/Documents/CUNEF/Tecnicas de Visualizacion/Trabajo_2_Shiny/app.R' is not a regular file
Warning in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) :
  cannot open file '/Users/octaviodelsueldo/Documents/CUNEF/Tecnicas de Visualizacion/Trabajo_2_Shiny/app.R': it is a directory
Error in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) : cannot open the connection
```

I don't know why this is happening. Down below I show you the code if any of these is incorrect.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Ejercicio 2 de Shiny"),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot", hover = "hover"), #el input hover se va a disparar cuando un usuario pase el raton en la grafica distplot. Su contenido es una lista de cosas.
           dataTableOutput("resultadoFiltro") #permite imprimir un dataframe de forma tabulada
        )
    
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # ReactiveVal es un reactivo que se puede modificar y hacer cosas como agregar o retirar lineas o columnas. 
    # ReactiveVal lo manipulamos nosotros directamente
    dataset <- reactiveVal({
        data.frame(x = rnorm(30), y = rnorm(30))
    })
    
    #Plot de la distribucion normal aleatoria creada
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(dataset(), aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
    })
    
    
    output$resultadoFiltro <- renderDataTable({
        nearPoints(dataset(), input$hover) #busca los puntos cercanos a una posicion. Esta funcion devuelve un dataframe con las filas seleccionadas
    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help you will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code works fine as is in Windows/RStudio.  Please make sure that you have downloaded Shiny and ggplot2.

Comment: Are you using RStudio? Have you tried to put your files in a path that doesn't contain any spaces?

Comment: Finally, I fix it using the app.R file into the same project area. I don't why when I create the app.R file was created another directory called `app` so the application doesn't run there.